# Matlab Plot Space of Solutions

Tags: matlab, function, variables, plot

I have a big problem :) I want to plot the Space of solutions `V(Prime,R)=V(0,0)`

Where : `V(prime;R) = p*u(R-D+q-prime)+(1-p)*u(R-prime)`
and `u=ln`

`R,D,p` are constant

I m a beginer with Matlab so I have absolutly no ideas to do this.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use the plot command?
http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html

```
        figure(1)
        plot(V(0,0))
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: no i don't see how i can use it... :'(

I just can use plot if I can simplify V(Prime,R)=V(0,0) to prime=f(q)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: Ho I''m sorry Ele I did a mistake, I want to plot all of couple (prime,q) witch verify :  V(Prime,q)=V(0,0)

Comment: Have you tried something like 

             if(V(Prime,q)=V(0,0)) 
                    plot(V(Prime,q))
             end
You may need a loop around it....